# Error getting correct blog_id on MU from functions.php

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I have script in my functions.php that seeks to locate the media directory of the site in which the theme is installed. This is pretty simple unless the site is an MU site. In that case, the media directory is based on the blog_id.

However, my code below is returning the main site id rather than the blog_id of the site in which its being run...

```
function get_image_list()
{
    global $current_site;
    $dir=is_multisite() ?  'wp-content/blogs.dir/'.$current_site->blog_id.'/files/' : 'wp-content/uploads/';
    $url=is_multisite() ?  get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/blogs.dir/'.$current_site->blog_id.'/files/' : get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/';
```

In this case, the actual blog_id is 3, however, its returning a value of 1 for $current_site->blog_id

The error is...

```
cannot open wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/
```

Comment: I got the the same problem but don't know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare `$current_site->id` with `$current_site->blog_id`.  According to the in-line documentation, `blog_id` should be working ... but check to see if there's a major difference there (your system might have a plug-in or something else causing a problem).

---

### Update - Ignore last

It seems like `$current_site` is a global variable defined by your *site* or *network* and will always return the same `blog_id` as your network dashboard - in this case, "1."

What you need to use instead is `$current_blog`:

```
function get_image_list() {
    global $current_blog;
    $dir=is_multisite() ?  'wp-content/blogs.dir/'.$current_blog->blog_id.'/files/' : 'wp-content/uploads/';
    $url=is_multisite() ?  get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/blogs.dir/'.$current_blog->blog_id.'/files/' : get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/';
```

That should get you the right information.

Answer (score 3):

Another gotcha is your hard coded `/wp-content/`.
Use `WP_CONTENT_DIR` for file access and `WP_CONTENT_URL` for HTTP requests or better yet [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) for both. I have some installations running where wp-content is on another domain and in a path outside of the WordPress directory.

So, even if you get the correct `blogi_id`, you may not find the files. :)

**Update**

My little debug plugin [Show Upload Info](https://gist.github.com/701718) may give some hints. But the results of `is_dir()` aren’t reliable, unfortunately.

Comment: Nice catch. (The devil is sticking in details *rofmlmaolol*)

Comment: that might be the solution. I'm finding that WPMU does not create the directory until something is first uploaded. Therefore, my check creates an error in that case. What is the output of wp_upload_dir() in that case?

Comment: It returns the correct directories, but doesn’t tell if they exist. Even `is_dir()` returns `true` – which may still be a lie. Strange.